# PHP5 doesn't work an a custom DocumentRoot

Tags: php, apache, configuration, document, root

I am currently struggling with the following problem.

I have successfully installed Apache2 and PHP5. And it works until I change the DocumentRoot of the Apache2 to something different than /var/www.

I want to set the DocumentRoot to /home//wwwroot, but after doing this all php pages are just white. (no download message or sth.)

Here is my php5.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
#    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
# SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
#    </FilesMatch>
#    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
# SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    # <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        # <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            # php_admin_value engine Off
        # </Directory>
    # </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I dont get it, and need help.

Thx!

Comment: What OS, please?  If CentOS/RHEL, check SELinux settings and logs.  If Ubuntu, check AppArmor settings and logs.  You might need to change settings to allow Apache to touch /home.  Also, this probably belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. Don't use `AddType`, as that breaks content negotiation.

```
LoadModule ...
<IfModule php5_module>
    #PHPIniDir "/whatever/"

    AddType text/html .php .phps
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried it, but no difference. Is #PHPIniDir important? Its a comment right?

Answer (score 0):

PHPIniDir is important if you want to use a different ini file for different php version, different website, server, etc.  i wouldn't delete it, i have a different ini files for windoze, for osx and for linux.